# Get current audio frequency amplitudes or spectrum in Linux Python

Tags: python, linux, audio, output, frequency

so currently I'm trying to make a **Python** script which reads the ALSA Mixer's output (or rather the general audio output) for the volumes/amplitudes of the current playing audio frequencies to trigger the GPIO ports on my Raspberry Pi, so I can effectively make an EQ out of LEDs responding to the current audio output. I want to create a real-time analysis (which is ***not bounded to the ALSA Mixer***, whatever works, works), so I can stream my music from my iPhone via Airplay to the Raspberry Pi or watch a YouTube video and the LED-EQ is, well, doing what it's supposed to do.

My problem is that I coudn't found any library or function in python on the Internet, which let's me get the **current audio output** or rather the **frequency amplitudes**. Does anybody have an idea of how to make this thing going?

P.S.: I tried Lightshowpi but I couldn't figure out how to use Shairport-sync with it, so if anyone has an answer to that, let me know it. :)

Edit:

If there's a way to get the wave form from the e.g. the last 8 Bytes of the audio stream I may do a fourier transformation (could a fourier transformation really work in a real-time environment, because of the heavy maths load on the CPU?)

Comment: I did similar kind of thing using PWM pin. You will get different level of voltage and you need to parse that so that your LED can respond based on the music.
check this out if helps http://www.instructables.com/id/RaspberryPi-Pulse-Width-Modulation-Demonstration/